# Query Results Not Writing to Table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to write the results of a query to an existing table. Recently, there has been no data written to the table, but the status says the task was completed. Any ideas what the issue could be?

```
"configuration": {
  "query": {
   "query": --,
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": --,
    "datasetId": --,
    "tableId": --
   },
   "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
   "priority": "INTERACTIVE",
   "allowLargeResults": true,
   "useQueryCache": true,
   "useLegacySql": false
  }
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "DONE"
 },
```

Comment: Hi Karly. I can take a look at the query details if you include project id and job id.

Comment: @Daria Thank you! 
project id: www-vendasta
job id: job_4VVGvY3WAqUw_ITLVNjt71UBauZT

Comment: This query produced 0 results, that's why no data was written to the destination table. You'll need to debug your SQL to figure out why the query doesn't produce results with your source tables, if expected. Using UI might be the most convenient option for this.

Answer (score 1):

state can be PENDING, RUNNING or DONE

DONE means query is completed

But to see if it is successfully completed or now you need to check `status.errorResult`